# Why is $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|$ true?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Sorry if this is very basic but here's a question.

Let $\mathbf{v}=(v_1,\ldots, v_n)\in k^n$ where $k=\bar{k}$.

> Why do we have
>   $$
> \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|, 
> $$
>   where the left-hand side can be thought of as the $2$-norm $\|\mathbf{v}\|_2$ on $L^2(k^n)$?

$\mathbf{General \; case}$: If this is true for $p=2$-norm, I am guessing that this is true for all $p\geq 1$: 
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|. 
$$

> In fact, does this inequality hold when $p$ is a rational number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Square both sides to get:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|\right)^2
$$

Expand the RHS using the [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) to see that it's equal to the LHS plus a number of non-negative terms. Hence the inequality holds.

Answer (score 4):

Or geometrically, the diagonal distance between opposite corners in an n-dimensional cuboid is smaller, than walking along the edges.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, yes the inequality holds for all rational $p\geq1$. In fact, the inequality holds for all $p\geq1.$

To see this note that the function $x\mapsto x^{p}$ is convex, so that if $x,y\geq0$, then

$$\frac{(x+y)^p-x^p}{(x+y)-x}\geq \frac{y^p-0^p}{y-0}\Rightarrow (x+y)^p\geq x^p+y^p.$$

By induction, if $x_i\geq0$,

$$(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^p\geq x_1^p+\cdots+x_n^p.$$

This is equivalent to your second assertion.

Comment: Nice, and thanks! So a similar argument can be applied to a family of convex functions!

Comment: @math-visitor: Yes, although in general you'll have an $nf(0)$ floating around.